# Python, composing srt file with mp4

Tags: mp4, subtitle, srt, video-subtitles

I am trying to automate subtitles . I have the subtitles but I don't know how can I compose it with video with a script( Normally I use VLC). Any API or library for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write something to use tha Handbrake command line instructions:

https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.3.0/cli/command-line-reference.html

```
 -F, --subtitle-forced[=string]
```